# HCL Domino 12.0.2 CA Process to obtain an internet SSL client certificate for HTTPS client Authetication

Tags: ssl, https, lotus-domino

I'm tryng to obtain an internet client SSL certificate to authenticate https client without need to type in user/password in HCL Domino 12.0.2.

Step to reproduce.

- Setup CA Process, this is up and running for standard Notes ID
- setup certmgr with Let's Encrypt ssl certificate at host webmail.mysite.com
- Registration - Internet Certifier - using CA Process, create a new certifier, casual common name/org/state (needs specific CN or other?)
- http internet site - security - allow authentication name and password enabled and client certificate enabled
- People and Groups - select person - Action - Add internet Cert to selected People
- Tell Adminp Process All (TAPA)
- Person doc - Actions - Create cross certificate - with CA cert doing cross certificate the internet certificate (needed?)
- TAPA
- (verified the internet certificate IS PRESENT, and Edit Examine internet Certificate shows it)
- Person Doc - Actions - Export internet certificate - create p12 file

In browser:

- import as personal the certificate p12 (unable to get in chrome the certificate in personal, in firefox it seems OK)
- opening webmail https site, i can see the domcfg configured login form, nothing happens

How do I need to trigger automatic SSL handshaking to get authenticated without type in user and password?

Comment: Point 1: Inet CA must have at minimum SHA256 sign algorithm